# Generic vs Non-Generic Overload Calling

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, overloading

When I declare a method like this:

```
void DoWork<T>(T a) { }
void DoWork(int a) { }
```

And call it with this:

```
int a = 1;
DoWork(a);
```

What `DoWork` method will it call and why? I can't seem to find it in any MSDN documentation.

Comment: It's easy to find out that it will call the second one (about 1 minute in visual studio shows that) but as to why, I could guess but somebody with more knowledge of the compiler should be able to give you a decent answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Eric Lippert [says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx):

> The C# specification says that when you have a choice between calling `ReallyDoIt<string>(string)` and `ReallyDoIt(string)` – that is, when the choice is between two methods that have identical signatures, but one gets that signature via generic substitution – then we pick the “natural” signature over the “substituted” signature.

UPDATE:

What we have in C# spec (7.5.3):

When a generic method is called without specifying type arguments, a type inference process attempts to infer type arguments for the call. Through type inference, the type argument int is determined from the argument to the method. Type inference occurs as part of the binding-time processing of a method invocation and takes place `before` the overload resolution step of the invocation.

When a particular method group is specified in a method invocation, and no type arguments are specified as part of the method invocation, type inference is applied to each generic method in the method group. If type inference succeeds, then the inferred type arguments are used to determine the types of arguments for subsequent overload resolution. If overload resolution chooses a generic method as the one to invoke, then the inferred type arguments are used as the actual type arguments for the invocation. If type inference for a particular method fails, that method does not participate in overload resolution.

So before overload resolution we have two methods in method group. One `DoWork(int)` and other inferred `DoWork<int>(int)`.

And we go to 7.5.3.2 (Better function member):

In case the parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …, QN} are equivalent (i.e. each Pi has an identity conversion to the corresponding Qi), the following tie-breaking rules are applied, in order, to determine the better function member. 
*1) If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.*

Comment: In the line _then **we** pick the “natural” signature over the “substituted” signature_, what do **we** mean, is it the compiler? And why would the _natural_ signature is preferable for such situation? Is it because of performance?

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona - There is some performance advantage here yes, as well as some flexibility advantages for the developer. The main reason why this choice is made is because the specs say so.

Comment: The tie-breaking rules are specified in section "7.4.3.2 Better function member" of [C# language spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc): **If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.** The logic behind this is: if you know how to deal with this specific type with non-generic method, the non-generic method wins; otherwise, fall back to generic methods.

Comment: See my comment about better function member selection.

Comment: It is not for performance, it is for specificity. If you have a method that says "I can frob a list of giraffes" and you have a method that says "I can frob a T for any type T you name", and then you say "Hey, I'd like to frob this list of giraffes", it seems reasonable that the compiler would choose the method that was designed to do precisely that.  Put another way: suppose we chose the generic method. **What code could you possibly write that would choose the non-generic one?**